# Coffeescript -how to dry up these two statements

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, dry

I have

```
alert 'yesb' if "blow" in ["slow", "flow", "blow"] 
alert 'nob' if "blow" not in ["slow", "flow", "blow"]
```

I would rather have

```
alert 'yesb' if "blow" in ["slow", "flow", "blow"] else alert "nob"
```

or

```
alert 'yesb' if "blow" in ["slow", "flow", "blow"] else "nob"
```

or

```
alert 'yesx' else alert 'nob' if "xrow" not in ["slow", "flow", "grow"]
```

or

```
alert 'yesx' else 'nob' if "xrow" not in ["slow", "flow", "grow"]
```

but they all give syntax errors.

Answer (score 3):

CoffeeScript's ternary if-then syntax is `if a > b then c else d`.

So what you're looking for is...

```
alert(if "blow" in ["slow", "flow", "blow"] then 'yesb' else 'nob')
```

Coming from Python I had this problem too because Python's syntax is `c if a > b else d`.

Comment: Whoa... i was quite (positively) surprised with [the resulting JavaScript](http://coffeescript.org/#try:alert%20if%20something%20in%20%5B%22slow%22%2C%20%22flow%22%2C%20%22blow%22%5D%20then%20'yesb'%20else%20'nob'%0A) for the `something in <array literal>` cases =D

Comment: @epidemian yah, right? I think a close second priority for the coffeescript compiler to producing efficient javascript code is producing human-readable javascript code.

Answer (score 1):

`if` is an expression in coffee-script, which means that you can use it just like the ternary operator `<condition> ? <if_true> : <else>` in JavaScript (or other c-like languages). It will return the last value. So you can use something like this:

```
alert if yourVar in ['slow', 'blow', 'grow'] then 'yes' else 'no'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why can't you use the most basic thing: An `if...else` statement.

```
if "blow" in ["slow", "flow", "blow"]
  alert "yesb"
else
  alert "nob"
```

Answer (score 0):

If I went with your first variation I think this would work:

```
if "blow" in ["slow", "flow", "blow"] alert 'yesb' else alert "nob"
```